# Displaying tiff image in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, tiff

I'm using Google maps and I want to display some portion of the image(tiff image) on the map based on conditions.Image should overlay on maps.

**Example**

In displaying the temperature of some area of japan, when I select a year, based on that year particular area of the image should overlay on the map.

How I can upload the tiff image on maps and uploaded image must overlay on the correct place. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

### Ground Overlays to the rescue

You can overlay an image in a map by using a ground overlay. Ground overlays are objects tied to latitude/longitude coordinates, so they move when you drag or zoom the map.

For more information about ground overlays, you can check the following documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/groundoverlays

### Code

I also have a code example from the documentation, where you can overlay a jpeg image on top of your map:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ground Overlays</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // This example uses a GroundOverlay to place an image on the map
     // showing an antique map of Newark, NJ.

    var historicalOverlay;

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: {
          lat: 40.740,
          lng: -74.18
        }
      });

      var imageBounds = {
        north: 40.773941,
        south: 40.712216,
        east: -74.12544,
        west: -74.22655
      };

      historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
        'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
        imageBounds);
      historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE**: In the example I am not using a key, so it works on StackOverflow. But as a user, you **should always** use an API Key or your website may be blocked by Google. Simply replace

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap
```

by

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```

### What about tiff?

At this point in time I am not completely sure we support the tiff format. The documentation on [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GroundOverlay) only mentions that you need to add an URL, but it does not specify anything about image types. In this case, you will have to try, but my educated guess is that *it should work*.

### What if `tiff` is not supported?

If the `tiff` format is not supported, you can always convert an image in that format to `png` or `jpeg`. Following are two links that will add you in this:

- http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-png
- http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

But there are many, many more out there.

I hope this answer aids you. If for some reason `tiff` is not supported, let me know so I can make a feature request !